# Button inside custom Callout View not responding (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, swift, mkannotationview

I have a custom MKPinAnnotationView created as so:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = false
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.pinColor = .Red
        pinView!.draggable = true;
    } else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Then I add a subview to it later with a button like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    view.addSubview(confirm)
}
```

The problem is that the button inside the subview is not responsive at all. What could be causing that? I already tried playing around with userInteraction enabled.
Thanks

Comment: You don't want to use the built-in rightCalloutAccessoryView or leftCalloutAccessoryView properties?  If you set them to a UIButton, tapping them will call the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this fits or helps but in my case I where I have similar code I set

```
pinView!.canShowCallout = true
```

and then if you want a simple way to catch the button clicks I put a func inside of my ViewContriller:

```
func buttonClicked (sender : UIButton!) {
    println("Button Clicked")
}
```

It sounds like you want to do something a bit different though.

Opps.. in previous answer I forgot that I added the button just above the

```
return pinView
```

....

```
    let button : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    return pinView
```

Now the buttonClicked func can catch the callout.

Comment: If I replace my current view with this nothing shows up when a pin is tapped... Do I still need to add a subview to the MKAnnotationView?